# Nginx proxy to backend allow doesnt work but deny works

Tags: apache, nginx

My target is to proxy my subdomain.domain.com via nginx to backend web.domain.domain.com that is on apache. proxy_pass works in nginx that part is ok

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name subdomain.domain.com;
location / {
 proxy_pass http://web.domain.domain.com;        
}}
```

So in this way i bring by web.domain.domain.com to world via subdomain.domain.com
But i doont what that everyone could access it so i know that nginx supports allow deny. When i add allow externalip and deny all to the code:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain.domain.com;
        location / {
allow xx.xx.xx.xx;
deny all;         
proxy_pass http://web.domain.domain.com;        
        }}
```

And it should allow ip to reach subdomain.domain.com and deny rest of the world but it doesnt work that way it denys all and thats it
I have red many post but didnt find any solution to this problem
Iam using nginx 1.6 version

Comment: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: no help? does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i didnt get real ip of users that reaches my domain, so the answer was that i needed to send real ip from my HA-proxy

```
    set_real_ip_from  10.x.x.x;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
```